# Why isn't <select> element populating?

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, dom

```
<select name="collectionsMongoDB" id="0" class="form-control">
    <%dbo.listCollections({}).toArray((err,collections)=>{%>
        <%if(err)throw err;%>
        <%collections.forEach((collection,i)=>{%>
            <option value=""><%=collection.name%></option>  
        <%})%>
    <%})%>
</select>
```

When I `<%console.log(collection.name)%>`, it displays the collections so the code is working. Alternatively, I'd like to know how to reference `dbo` object in `<script>` tag. Thanks!

Comment: Wait, when you console log `collection.name` it prints entire collections? Either that's incredibly wrong, or you've not actually described what _really_ happens, so: can you rephrase your text to be precise? Ideally, don't describe what happens, show what happens by showing the code with that console.log in there, and showing what the resulting output is.

Comment: Hi Mike! It does. When I `<%console.log(collection.name);%>` it console logs the names of collection

Comment: "don't describe what happens, show what happens by showing the code with that console.log in there, and showing what the resulting output is". Please update your post.